# WebDriver Proper Shutdown

Tags: java, webdriver, driver, shutdown

I'm wondering for a while now what the best way was to do a proper clean-up after an expection has been thrown or the testcase has finished.

As a reminder:
An .exe process driver process according to the implementation, conhost.exe, the browser and Java application are launched.

Using `driver.quit()`, we can kill the driver process, conhost and browser after finishing the testcase.

```
WebDriver driver = new SomethingDriver();

// do stuff

driver.quit(); // Proper cleaning
```

However, if an exception may be thrown, we need to do this:

```
    try{
        WebDriver driver = new SomethingDriver();

        // do stuff
    }
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}        
    finally{
        driver.quit(); // Proper cleaning
    }
```

What about shutting down the driver process and conhost, but leaving the browser alive? Executing a shell script is bad since it kills *all* the processes with these names (therefore prevents concurrent usage) and it is Windows only (I think):

```
TASKKILL /F /IM chromedriver.exe
TASKKILL /F /IM conhost.exe
```

Let's say we kill the Java process randomly (in Eclipse or task manager). How can we make sure that above mentioned cleaning takes place?

Is there a code solution which covers all these issues nicely?

Answer (score 0):

Using JUnit can help

```
public class JunitTest1 {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetUp() {
        // one-time initialization code   
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass - oneTimeSetUp");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void oneTimeTearDown() {
        // one-time cleanup code
        System.out.println("@AfterClass - oneTimeTearDown");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // before every test
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println("@Before - setUp");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // after every test
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("@After - tearDown");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSmthOne() {
        // the test itself
        System.out.println("@Test - testSmth");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSmthTwo() {
        // the test itself
        System.out.println("@Test - testSmth");
    }
}
```